# Jasmine + AngularJS unit test a rest call

Tags: unit-testing, rest, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write some tests for my rest calls and I am trying to figure out how to make a unique rest call per `it` declaration.  For example:

```
describe('My testing',function()
{  
    var $scope;
    var controller;
    var httpBackend;
    var http;  

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller,$http,$httpBackend)  
    {  
             $scope = $rootScope.new();  
             http = $http;  
             httpBackend = $httpBackend;
             httpBackend.when("GET","https://my/rest/call").respond([]);  
             controller = $controller('MyCtrl',{  
                 $scope:$scope,  
                 $http:$http  
             });  
    }));    

    it('my test',function()  
    {  
       expect($scope.results).toEquals([]);  
       httpBackend.flush();  
    });  
});
```

Works just fine.  How can I make it so I can do a unique call in each `it`?  For example:

```
it('empty test',function()  
        {    
           httpBackend.when("GET","https://my/rest/call").respond([]);  
           expect($scope.results).toEquals([]);  
           httpBackend.flush();  
        });  


it('one test',function()  
        {    
           httpBackend.when("GET","https://my/rest/call").respond([{1:"one"}]);  
           expect($scope.results).toEquals([]);  
           httpBackend.flush();  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expect` instead of `when`. Unlike `when` which fulfills all requests that match, `expect` will only fulfill one request at a time. Thus you can tell it what you want it to respond with each time.

Just be aware that the test will fail if the requests come in in a different order than how the `expect`s where configured. The tests will also fail if there was never a request made to one that was configured in an `expect`.

Comment: Based on your question, I think so. The $httpBacked documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend) has a nice table the lays out the differences between `expect` and `when`

Answer (score 0):

First of remove that .when in beforeEach if you will expect different responses, define them then in your test. Second, what is actually doing a call to the remote service. I see only that you are setting up what should be returned when that particular url is hit but no call to the backend. Here is two tests samples

```
describe("inSearchDataSvc", function () {

    var inSearchDataSvc;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(function () {

        //mockConfig = { dataServiceHostName: "http://myhost" };

        module(function ($provide) {
            //     $provide.value('config', mockConfig);
            //    $provide.value('$q', mockQ);
            //    $provide.value('config', mockConfig);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            inSearchDataSvc = $injector.get('inSearchDataSvc');
        });

    });

      it("should return resolved promise", function () {

                $httpBackend.when('GET', /.*\/api\/insureds\/searchinsureds\?.*/).respond(200, { result: "result" });

                 var searchCriteria = new InsuredSearchCriteria();

                 $httpBackend.expectGET(searchUrl + "?clientId=&dateOfBirth=&emailAddress=&firstName=&includeExpiredInsureds=false&includeK12LineOfBusinessInsureds=false&lastName=&searchId=");

                var promiseResult;

                inSearchDataSvc.getInsureds(searchCriteria)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        promiseResult = result;
                    });

                $httpBackend.flush();

                expect(promiseResult.$resolved).toBe(true);
                expect(promiseResult.result).toBe("result");
            });

            it("it should reject promise if server throws and error", function() {

                $httpBackend.when('GET', /.*\/api\/insureds\/searchinsureds\?throwError=true/).respond(400, { error: "Bad Query" });

                var promiseResult;
                var returnedError;

                var searchCriteria = {throwError:true};

               $httpBackend.expectGET(searchUrl + "?throwError=true");

                inSearchDataSvc.getInsureds(searchCriteria)
                   .then(
                       function (result) { },
                       function (error) {
                       returnedError = error;

                   });

                $httpBackend.flush();

                expect(returnedError.data.error).toBe("Bad Query");
            });
});
```